# For $a,b,c,d \in [-1,1]$, is $|ab-cd| \le |a-c| + |b-d|$?

Tags: inequality

The title pretty much says it.   Suppose $a,b,c,d \in [-1,1]$.  I wish to prove the inequality
$$|ab-cd| \le |a-c| + |b-d|.$$
This must be very elementary, but for some reason I'm stuck.  Various attempts to rearrange or square both sides didn't seem helpful.

This inequality arises in showing a "Leibniz rule" property for Dirichlet forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add and subtract a cross term:

$$|ab-cd|=|ab-ad+ad-cd| \leq |a||b-d|+|d||a-c| \,.$$

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks very much, you saved me a couple hours of staring.